# Perforce deleted files from explorer, how to sync?

Tags: perforce

I have deleted a couple of image files from my workspace through the windows explorer (I left one file in that folder), then I went to my visual client and hit "Get Latest". Nothing happened, I worked through the terminal and did `p4 sync -f` in the parent folder, nothing was brought back either. I guess because I've deleted the files by hand Perforce wasn't able to relate to those files.

My workaround was:

```
Checking out those deleted files from the depo (it would warn that the file won't exist)
Revert them. The revert brought back the missing files from the depot.
```

Is there a better workflow dealing with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `p4 clean` command.  This will automatically re-sync everything that is different or missing (or, in the case of extra files that weren't added to the depot, delete them).

https://web.archive.org/web/20150107135057/http://www.perforce.com/blog/140501/p4-clean-make-workspace-shine

Comment: I've realized just today, that when I delete something, and then go to `p4v` and use `RMB > clean...` I'm getting "files not opened on this client. Any Ideas?

Comment: I don't even see a "clean" command in my P4V right-click menu, so no clue what it's doing.  Just running `p4 clean` from the command line should do the right thing.